# Why is -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize not getting applied?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot

I tried to understand how `-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m` works but it did not get applied when running java as follows:

`java --version -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m`

It simply set to the default `48M` on `x86` at this [point](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/hotspot/cpu/x86/c2_globals_x86.hpp#l87):

```
define_pd_global(uintx, ReservedCodeCacheSize,       48*M);
```

And then got 5 times increased at that [point](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/hotspot/share/compiler/compilerDefinitions.cpp#l201):

```
// Increase the code cache size - tiered compiles a lot more.
if (FLAG_IS_DEFAULT(ReservedCodeCacheSize)) {
    FLAG_SET_ERGO(uintx, ReservedCodeCacheSize,
                  MIN2(CODE_CACHE_DEFAULT_LIMIT, (size_t)ReservedCodeCacheSize * 5));
  }
```

causing [reservation code space](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/hotspot/share/code/codeCache.cpp#l303) to `48*5 M` instead of the value I configured:

```
size_t cache_size         = ReservedCodeCacheSize;
//...
ReservedCodeSpace rs = reserve_heap_memory(cache_size);
```

I first though that `ReservedCodeCacheSize` is a development option and therefore not allowed to be overriden, but it is marked as product [here](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/hotspot/share/runtime/globals.hpp#l1881) so this is not the case.

What's wrong and why was the option silently ignored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`--version` is a [terminal option](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/95937fc2a05e/src/java.base/share/native/libjli/args.c#l446). JVM flags should precede terminal options.

Try `java -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m --version`

Comment: I tried to set `ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m` and `ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m` and it works as expected. While trying to set it to `128m` or less it does not seem to even go through the point where code cache is getting reserved: `ReservedCodeSpace rs = reserve_heap_memory(cache_size);`. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @SomeName Because for heaps smaller than 240M `SegmentedCodeCache` [is not enabled](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/95937fc2a05e/src/hotspot/share/compiler/compilerDefinitions.cpp#l204), and the reservation goes through another path.

Comment: Actually, did not notice that the path was after checking the `SegmentedCodeCache` flag [here](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/hotspot/share/code/codeCache.cpp#l1105). Thanks much.